# Regex for line beginning with a character and ending with either of the characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex pattern that grabs string between the first occurrence of character where it begins with "/" and may end with either "/" or "//" or none. For example -

```
/test1/code1
/test/code1/code2
/test/code1//code2
```

All of above should return code1.

I tried following regex -

```
\/+.*?(\/|\/\/)(.*)
```

However, this only stops at / following test1 and returns everything. i.e. /code1//code2.

Any suggestion on how I can ensure that the look up is for beginning with / and ending with either / or // or none?

Comment: Strict regular expressions don't give you tools for that, but you programming language probably does. Which language are you using?

Comment: you can use [**^\/(.+?)(\/|$)**](https://regex101.com/r/BSPgQd/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do the job:

```
/.+?/([^/]+)(?:/|$)
```

The result is in group 1.

**Explanation:**

```
/       : a slash
.+?     : one or more any character not greedy
/       : a slash
([^/]+) : one or more any character that is not a slash
(?:/|$) : Non capturing group either a slash or line end
```

Here is a perl script using this regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dumper;

my $re = qr!/.+?/([^/]+)(?:/|$)!;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say (/$re/ ? "OK: \$1=$1\t $_" : "KO: $_");
}

__DATA__
/test1/code1
/test/code1/code2
/test/code1//code2
```

**Output:**

```
OK: $1=code1     /test1/code1
OK: $1=code1     /test/code1/code2
OK: $1=code1     /test/code1//code2
```